# Looking for some kind of "lookahead iteration" for grouping record sets

Tags: php, cycle

as it use to be, if you need to display list of something on site you have to use some looping construct to iterate over data.

In my case it's foreach() on `<tr>` of the table

```
foreach($candidates as $candidate)
```

and after that I am getting to values:

```
$candidate->id
```

Problem is one specific value, and it is enforcement. In my DB I have data like in table below, so for example for `candidates_id` = 600 there are enforcemement 1 and 0

```
id  |  candidates_id  | enforcement 
-------------------------------------
1   |       598       |      2
2   |       599       |      4
3   |       600       |      1
4   |       600       |      0
```

Until now everything is OKEY, I get values from DB and I echo it on site. Problem is that values like 0 or 1 have no meaning for end user. so I write IF / ELSE condition

```
if($candidate->enfor == 0)
 echo "TEXT1";
elseif($candidate->enfor == 1)
 echo "TEXT2";
else
 echo "some default text";
```

In the sample data there are two records with candidates_id=600 and different values for enforcement.
Right now the script produces two separate `<tr>` elements. One containing `<td>TEXT1</td>` and the other `<td>TEXT2</td>`.
I'm looking for a way to output `<td>TEXT1,TEXT2</td>` in the same html table row and column based on the fact that there are those two records for candidate_id=600 in the database.
I try to make another cycle for this but without any success. 
I am not even sure if I am thinking right way.

Can someone advise me how to make this work?

EDIT:
my Query to DB is:

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstname, c.surname, c.email, c.process, c.search_work, c.note,c.registration_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN cl.language = 'angličtina' THEN cl.level ELSE '-' END)AS 'en',
       MAX(CASE WHEN cl.language = 'němčina' THEN cl.level ELSE '-' END)AS 'ge',
       group_concat(DISTINCT ce.enforcement) as enfor,  
       group_concat(DISTINCT cc.city) as city  
FROM candidates AS c
LEFT JOIN candidates_languages AS cl ON c.id = cl.candidates_id
LEFT JOIN candidates_enforcement as ce on c.id = ce.candidates_id
LEFT JOIN candidates_city as cc on c.id = cc.candidates_id
GROUP BY c.id, c.firstname, c.surname, c.email DESC
```

Comment: what's the query you're using to retrieve data from db?

Comment: degr sorry , looks my english is not that well, how can I help you understand?
@RodrigoKravetz Added QUERY

Comment: According to the table you have a field named enforcement, but you're making a reference to a property named enfor. Can you please show us your query?

Comment: Where is your if? It should be inside the foreach and will be applied each time.

Comment: @VicAbreu group_concat(DISTINCT ce.enforcement) as enfor,  so it should be OK :|,  Lelio it is inside of foreach this is the reason it display all values but if / else work just for one

Comment: In your query you have a group_concat, so it will going to display (0,1) for id = 600. You have to use the explode() function in order to put the values into an array and then do the cycle.

Comment: if you're using GROUP_CONCAT, then you will have a "enfor" result for id 600 as 0,1 (if I'm correct). use explode (",", $ro) and then use foreach again

Comment: if I understand you correctly, because of GROUP_CONCAT result I get (so 0,1) is 1x string not 2x integer, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is the `group_concat` in your query that will return `0,1` for the `id=600`. You should do something like this:

```
foreach($candidates as $candidate){
    // do your things ...
    $enfor_array = explode(',', $candidate->enfor);
    foreach($enfor_array as $enf) {
       if($enf == 0)
          echo "TEXT1";
       elseif($enf == 1)
          echo "TEXT2";
       else
          echo "some default text";
    }
}
```